# Assigning value of an object to another - they mustn't point same adresses at memory

Tags: java, memory, variable-assignment

I have a problem with getting a new value of an object. I have a code like that:

```
...
TimeSchedule[] offspringScheduleOne = new TimeSchedule[AVAILABLE_CLASSROOMS];
...
offspringScheduleOne[i] = genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i];
...
```

After that assignment offspringScheduleOne[i] and genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i] points the **same memory address**. I want that: `offspringScheduleOne[i]` should get the value of the `genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i]`, they musn't be same, **they just should have same values**.

TimeSchedule class:

```
public class TimeSchedule extends AlgorithmParameters {
    public int[][] timetable = new int[DAYS][HOURS];//DAYS and HOURS are static final variables that comes from AlgorithmParameters 

    public int[][] getTimetable() {
        return timetable;
    }

    public void setTimetable(int[][] timetable) {
        this.timetable = timetable;
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The title of your question (*they must point same adresses at memory*) says about the contrary of the text (*they just should have same values*) - what do you want, in fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually *is* copying the value - but you need to understand what that value is.

The value of `offspringScheduleOne[0]` isn't a `TimeSchedule` object. It's a *reference* to a `TimeSchedule` object. *No expression in Java has a value which is an object.* It's really important that you understand this.

Now, if you want a *copy* of the object, you'll have to make that happen yourself. For example, you could include a `clone()` method in `TimeSchedule`, and write:

```
offspringScheduleOne[i] = genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i].clone();
```

In other words, create a clone of the existing object, and then set `offspringScheduleOne[i]` to be a reference to that newly created object. Of course, if any of the fields within `TimeSchedule` is a reference type field, you'll need to consider whether or not you need to clone *that* object as well...

... or you could add a constructor and call that, or another method, etc. But you need to be absolutely clear that the assignment operator *is* copying the value, but that value is a reference.

EDIT: Okay, now that you've posted `TimeSchedule`, a few suggestions:

- Stop using public fields. What's the point of having properties if the field is public?
- Rather than having properties returning the whole array, change them to access an individual hour, e.g.

  ```
  public int getTimetable(int day, int hour) {
      // TBD: Argument validation
      return timetable[day][hour];
  }

  // Similar for `setTimetable`
  ```
- Create a clone method like this:

  ```
  public TimeSchedule clone() {
      TimeSchedule copy = new TimeSchedule();
      for (int i = 0; i < timetable.length; i++) {
          copy.timetable[i] = timetable[i].clone();
      }
      return copy;
  }
  ```

  (That's slightly wasteful in that it will create the subarrays and then discard them, but let's get something which works first...)
  }

  public Test clone() {
      int[][] timetableCopy = new int[timetable.length][];
      for (int i = 0; i < timetable.length; i++) {
          timetableCopy[i] = timetable[i].clone();
      }
      return null;
  }

Comment: I have edited my code and included code of TimeSchedule class. What you suggest to write that clone method?

Comment: @kamaci: Basically you'd need to clone the array of arrays within TimeSchedule. Will edit.

Comment: I will consider your advices. Your solution is pretty good. Accepting your answer and voting up for your extra advices. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new TimeSchedule object. Assuming you have a copy constructor you can use this:

```
TimeSchedule original = genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i];
TimeSchedule copy = new TimeSchedule(original);
offspringScheduleOne[i] = copy;
```

The constructor should copy the values from original. If you don't have such a constructor you can call get and set methods to copy the values across manually.

```
TimeSchedule original = genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i];

TimeSchedule copy = new TimeSchedule();
copy.setFoo(original.getFoo());
copy.setBar(original.getBar());
// etc...

offspringScheduleOne[i] = copy;
```

There's also a [`clone`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) method that was designed for creating copies of objects, but it's awkward to use and it's probably best to avoid it.

Comment: I read your answer and I want to learn more about clone method. How is Jon Skeet's answer? Overriding that clone method or your answer, can you compare them which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

You could let TimeSchedule override the clone method and write

```
offspringScheduleOne[i] = genes.get(geneOneIndex).getSchedule()[i].clone();
```